# Java Deserialisation - Am I affected?

Tags: java, security, java-security

I'm referring to the Java Deserialisation vulnerability

(Info: https://www.christian-schneider.net/JavaDeserializationSecurityFAQ.html#main & https://github.com/GrrrDog/Java-Deserialization-Cheat-Sheet )

and I'm currently using the frameworks listed here:

```
- Axis 1.4
- Axis-jaxrpc 1.4
- Apache Commons Beanutils 1.9.3
    -> Not affected (since 1.9.3) ?? 
- Apache Commons Collections 3.2.2
    -> Not affected (since 3.2.2 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-580)
- Apache Commons Discovery 0.5
- Apache Commons Fileupload 1.3.2
    -> AFFECTED (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-279)
- Apache Commons Logging 1.2
- Apache Commons Net 3.5
- EHCache Core 2.6.11
- Google gson 2.8.0
- Guava 21.0
- Java Mail API 1.5.6
- Java servlet API 3.1.0
- Java websocket API 1.1
- jsch 0.1.54
- log4j2 API 2.7
- log4j2 Core 2.7
- Apache Shiro 1.3.2
    - Shiro Core 1.3.2
    - Shiro EHCache 1.3.2
    - Shiro Spring 1.3.2
    - Shiro Web 1.3.2
    -> Not affected (since 1.2.5 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-550)
- slf4j API 1.7.22
- slf4j Simple 1.7.22
- WSDL4j 1.6.3
```

in my webapplication running on Tomcat 8.0.32 (not affected) and I already found out that 1 is affected and 2 are not affected (at least the version I use)

**Does anyone know if the other frameworks are affected by this vulnerability?**

**Or how I can check if they are affected when a google search doesn't give me any information about a framework being affected or not?**

**Edit: Am I safe If I do NOT use the following in my code?**

- `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`
- `ObjectInputStream.readUnshared()`
- XStream

Comment: Do you deserialise untrusted data?

Comment: The code that I wrote does not use `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` or `ObjectInputStream.readUnshared()` at all no do I use `XStream` but as far as I can tell this doent mean that an application is safe. Some Framework might use it and thats where you could get "attacked"

Comment: No. You can **only** be attacked if you find some random, serialized, Java data on the internet and load it. If your application does not do this then it cannot be compromised by this attack vector.

Comment: Thats the point I dont quite understand since I read about this attack being a big issue even when you are not actively deserializing. Thats where the used frameworks come in and where it can be hard to identify where some method of framework X at some point deserialises data.